# Переключение табов через кнопки

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать переключение табов по кнопкам. что я делаю не так.
Благодарю за внимание.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-triggers__item').forEach((item) =>
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');

    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-triggers__item').forEach(
      (child) => child.classList.remove('tabs-triggers__item_active')
    );

    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-content__item').forEach(
      (child) => child.classList.remove('tabs-content__item_active')
    );

    item.classList.add('tabs-triggers__item_active');
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('tabs-content__item_active');
  })
);

document.querySelector('.tabs-triggers__item').click();

const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.tabs-button__prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.tabs-button__next');
const triggers = document.querySelector('.tabs-triggers__item');
const content = document.querySelector('.tabs-content__item');

btnNext.addEventListener('click', function() {

  const id = triggers.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
  triggers.classList.remove('tabs-triggers__item_active');
  triggers.nextElementSibling.classList.add('tabs-triggers__item_active');
  content.classList.remove('tabs-content__item_active');
  document.getElementById(id).nextElementSibling
    .classList.add('tabscontent__item_active');

});

btnPrev.addEventListener('click', function() {

  const id = triggers.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
  triggers.classList.remove('tabs-triggers__item_active');
  triggers.previousElementSibling.classList.add('tabs-triggers__item_active');
  content.classList.remove('tabs-content__item_active');
  document.getElementById(id).previousElementSibling
    .classList.add('tabs-content__item_active');

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs-triggers {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabs-content {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabs-triggers__item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
}

.tabs-triggers__item_active {
  background: #118BDD;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs-content__item {
  display: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tabs-content__item_active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs-button__prev,
.tabs-button__next {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-triggers">
      <a href="#tab-1" class="tabs-triggers__item">1</a>
      <a href="#tab-2" class="tabs-triggers__item">2</a>
      <a href="#tab-3" class="tabs-triggers__item">3</a>
      <a href="#tab-4" class="tabs-triggers__item">4</a>
      <a href="#tab-5" class="tabs-triggers__item">5</a>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs-content">
      <div id="tab-1" class="tabs-content__item">Content 1</div>
      <div id="tab-2" class="tabs-content__item">Content 2</div>
      <div id="tab-3" class="tabs-content__item">Content 3</div>
      <div id="tab-4" class="tabs-content__item">Content 4</div>
      <div id="tab-5" class="tabs-content__item">Content 5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs-buttons">
      <button class="tabs-button__prev" type="button" name="button"><</button>
      <button class="tabs-button__next" type="button" name="button">></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно плодить дублирующие функции - все необходимые действия происходят в обработчике клика по элементам `.tabs-triggers__item`. Поэтому достаточно просто инициировать событие клика на нужном элементе:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-triggers__item').forEach((item) =>
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');

    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-triggers__item').forEach(
      (child) => child.classList.remove('tabs-triggers__item_active')
    );

    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-content__item').forEach(
      (child) => child.classList.remove('tabs-content__item_active')
    );

    item.classList.add('tabs-triggers__item_active');
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('tabs-content__item_active');
  })
);

document.querySelector('.tabs-triggers__item').click();

const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.tabs-button__prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.tabs-button__next');

btnNext.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let current = document.querySelector(".tabs-triggers__item_active");
  (current.nextElementSibling || current.parentElement.children[0]).click();
});

btnPrev.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let current = document.querySelector(".tabs-triggers__item_active");
  (current.previousElementSibling || current.parentElement.children[current.parentElement.children.length - 1]).click();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs-triggers {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabs-content {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabs-triggers__item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
}

.tabs-triggers__item_active {
  background: #118BDD;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs-content__item {
  display: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tabs-content__item_active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs-button__prev,
.tabs-button__next {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-triggers">
      <a href="#tab-1" class="tabs-triggers__item">1</a>
      <a href="#tab-2" class="tabs-triggers__item">2</a>
      <a href="#tab-3" class="tabs-triggers__item">3</a>
      <a href="#tab-4" class="tabs-triggers__item">4</a>
      <a href="#tab-5" class="tabs-triggers__item">5</a>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs-content">
      <div id="tab-1" class="tabs-content__item">Content 1</div>
      <div id="tab-2" class="tabs-content__item">Content 2</div>
      <div id="tab-3" class="tabs-content__item">Content 3</div>
      <div id="tab-4" class="tabs-content__item">Content 4</div>
      <div id="tab-5" class="tabs-content__item">Content 5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs-buttons">
      <button class="tabs-button__prev" type="button" name="button"><</button>
      <button class="tabs-button__next" type="button" name="button">></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас!!!